# Confirm payment in the paypal page before redirecting to the site

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

How can we confirm paypal payment using express checkout before redirecting to the site.
It asks "Confirm Order" after redirecting to the site from the paypal account.
How can we able to confirm the order directly in the paypal and redirect to the thank you page or order recieved page?

Answer (score 2):

when you post data to paypal specify this field with callback url

```
<input type="text" name="notify_url" value="http://paypal.mysite.com" />
```

when user pays, paypal do POST to this url with transaction info
some info are

```
public string payer_email { get; set; }
public string payer_firstname { get; set; }
public string payer_lastname { get; set; }
public string payer_address { get; set; }
public string payer_city { get; set; }
public string payer_country { get; set; }
public string payment_status { get; set; }
public string pending_reason { get; set; }
public string payment_date { get; set; }
public double mc_gross { get; set; }
public double mc_fee { get; set; }
public string address_country { get; set; }
public string address_city { get; set; }
public string first_name { get; set; }
public string last_name { get; set; }
public string address_street { get; set; }
public string verify_sign { get; set; }
```

for example, if you are using PHP you can do this to know all returned values

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key)
{
    $value .= $key .": " . $_POST[$key]."<br/>";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (message, date) VALUES ('$value', NOW()) ");
```